# How to get the crash report for an iphone app

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

So I am not sure what is going on.

When I run the app on the simulator or on my actual device while connected to xcode, everything works as desired.

The debug panel shows me all my print statements etc... (both simulator and actual device)

This is where is goes bad, when the app is on the real device and I run it (xcode is no longer logging anything cause I am running it directly from the real phone) the app crashes and since I'm not connected to xcode I can not see the issue!?

It NEVER crashes when I running it from xcode... which I wish it would so I could get an idea of why its crashing.

Does anyone know how I can get the crash report for an app I just loaded to my phone directly from xcode!?

Answer (score 3):

1. Attach device via USB to the computer
2. Open Xcode, navigate to "Devices" window from the "Window" menu
3. Select your device
4. Click "View Device Logs"
5. Choose "All logs"
6. View stored crash logs from your device

Comment: Did this help answer your question?